# American English

Tags: american-english, got-gotten

I notice that Americans use the word 'gotten' when we in Britain just use 'got' - is 'gotten' accepted American English, that is, used and accepted in English examination papers, or is it a type of slang, used in speech, but not written?

The previous answer you directed me to doesn't quite answer my question, although it was interesting. I can deduce from it, however, that 'gotten', if used correctly, is indeed acceptable and an actual word, is that right?

Comment: Not all *got*'s should be replaced by *gotten*, just some of them.

Comment: Do they have English examinations in America? Would that not amount to so-called 'proscriptivism', which many people on this site seem to regard as tantamount to Lord North's Stamp Act.